# Tables not knitting and printing out within Rmd notebook?

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I am trying to preview a table within my Rmd notebook without knitting the whole document. When I call:

```
xtable(anthro_table_f)
```

I get:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.5.1 by xtable 1.8-3 package
% Sun Sep 16 16:10:36 2018
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & Male & Female & p & test \\ 
  \hline
n & 708 & 219 &  &  \\ 
  HeightCm (mean (sd)) & 175.78 (7.10) & 163.65 (8.32) & $<$0.001 &  \\ 
  WeightKg (mean (sd)) & 78.11 (10.95) & 63.59 (8.86) & $<$0.001 &  \\ 
  BMI (mean (sd)) & 25.27 (3.19) & 23.80 (3.41) & $<$0.001 &  \\ 
  HI\_LateralityQuotient (mean (sd)) & 0.76 (0.43) & 0.87 (0.24) & 0.001 &  \\ 
  NeckLengthCm (mean (sd)) & 19.03 (2.98) & 17.39 (3.35) & $<$0.001 &  \\ 
  NeckCircCm (mean (sd)) & 38.29 (2.45) & 32.41 (2.05) & $<$0.001 &  \\ 
  HeadCircCm (mean (sd)) & 58.03 (1.84) & 56.28 (1.91) & $<$0.001 &  \\ 
  NeckVolumeCm (mean (sd)) & 2237.03 (483.68) & 1467.40 (363.38) & $<$0.001 &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

instead of the actual table below the code. When I knit the whole document, the table appears as expected. How do I get the actual table?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is incorrect here, you just need to understand what it happening.

(*I'll discuss generally what happens when you knit a document.  Your specific question is addressed at the bottom of my answer.*)

Let's say you create an RMD file and you want to knit it to PDF. When you click "knit" in RStudio, a few things happen.

- First, the R code is run, and the code and output (depending on your chunk options) are saved as TEX. This TEX also includes the non-R-code parts of your original RMD document (e.g., paragraphs, sections, etc.).
- Then, pdfLatex (or luaLatex or whatever Latex engine you use) converts that TEX file to a PDF file.

Here's the process in pictures:

---

#### 1) You create an RMD file:

[image]

---

#### 2) `knitr` "converts" your RMD document to a TEX document (Usually, you never see this part):

[image]

---

#### 3) pdfLatex converts that TEX document to a PDF document:

[image]

---

So finally, regarding your specific question. `xtable`'s output is designed for that second step (the TEX file). When you call `xtable(anthro_table_f)` in RStudio, that table (in Latexy form) is printed to the R console.

Comment: Can someone with moderator privileges and knowledge of SO formatting please make my post more readable? I read up on how to change image sizes on SO, but I was unable to find an option that looked good. Thank you!

Comment: Ah I see- is there a way to get it to print in the actual form (non-Latexy) to the console?

Comment: With `xtable`, no.  With some other package, maybe, but I don't know of any.